# Reading configuration file with a map of properties in Quarkus

Tags: java, yaml, quarkus, microprofile

My `application.yaml` has a map of values stored in a yaml file.

```
app:
  myMap:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key3: value3
```

Configuration class:

```
@Data
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppConfiguration {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "app.myMap")
    private Map<String, String> myMap;
}
```

This results in the following error: 
`javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: No config value of type [java.util.Map] exists for: app.myMap`

I'm unable to read these values because MicroProfile does not support `java.util.Map`. I came across [this mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/quarkus-dev/c/oTHlRdDO7RE) that suggests a workaround but being rather new to Quarkus, I'm unsure of how to implement this properly. It's also a year old and I'm wondering if there is a better implementation then what was suggested in that mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed there is a better way now. Quarkus configuration is implemented by SmallRye Config. Unfortunately, it doesn't support Map direct injection directly, but you can use a mapping object like documented here: https://smallrye.io/docs/smallrye-config/main/mapping/mapping.html

Here is an example project:
https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-config/tree/main/examples/mapping

All of this works in Quarkus.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a config mapping that's provided through the `@ConfigMapping` interface.

## Using a YAML configuration

Since your specific case deals with YAML, you can do the following ...

### Code

First, make sure you don't forget to provide the respective dependency to enable
YAML configuration:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-config-yaml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The configuration you want to apply is `application.yaml`:

```yaml
app:
  myMap:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key3: value3
```

The respective config mapping can be implemented like this:

```java
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "app")
public interface AppConfig {

    @WithName("myMap")
    Map<String, String> myMap();
}
```

Calling the configuration in your code is then straightforward, eg.:

```java
@Path("/ping")
public class PingResource {

    @Inject
    AppConfig appConfig;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String ping() {
        String v1 = appConfig.myMap().get("key1");
        String v2 = appConfig.myMap().get("key2");
        String v3 = appConfig.myMap().get("key3");
        return "Values: [" + v1 + ":" + v2 + ":" + v3 + "]\n";
    }
}
```

## Using an `application.properties` file

In case you want to use an `application.properties` instead, do the following ...

### Code

If you want to use an `application.properties` , we don't need the
`quarkus-config-yaml` Maven dependency.

The `application.properties` then becomes:

```
app.myMap.key1=value1
app.myMap.key2=value2
app.myMap.key3=value3
```

The code for the config mapping keeps being the same:

```java
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "app")
public interface AppConfig {

    @WithName("myMap")
    Map<String, String> myMap();
}
```

... as well as the logic to fetch it:

```java
@Path("/ping")
public class PingResource {

    @Inject
    AppConfig appConfig;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String ping() {
        String v1 = appConfig.myMap().get("key1");
        String v2 = appConfig.myMap().get("key2");
        String v3 = appConfig.myMap().get("key3");
        return "Values: [" + v1 + ":" + v2 + ":" + v3 + "]\n";
    }
}
```

## Reference

https://quarkus.io/guides/config-yaml

https://quarkus.io/guides/config-mappings